# How can I connect my Xamarin.Forms mobile application to web services PROPERLY?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Good Day. I'm just a newbie in using Xamarin.Forms so guys please help me. I created a basic mobile application. I also created an ASP.NET WEB APPLICATION that enable me to CRUD record of an Employee's Name and Department. What I want to do is to get all the records I have created in the website and show it to my mobile application. But I'm having trouble CONNECTING XAMARIN.FORMS to WEB SERVICE. I was able to save records in the WEB APP but when I tried to connect it to my mobile application, it didn't work. This is a cross platform but I'm focusing first on the android version so for now please disregard iOS and Windows. Please help me. If I'm on the wrong path on doing this or if you have another idea just please let me know.
I hope my codes will help. Thanks a lot.

MainPageMain.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="XamarinDemo.Views.MainPageMain"
         xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:XamarinDemo.ViewModels;assembly=XamarinDemo"
         BackgroundColor="Teal">

  <ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ViewModels:MainViewModel/>
  </ContentPage.BindingContext>

 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeesList}"
       HasUnevenRows="True">
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
       <ViewCell>
         <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                  Padding="12,6">
           <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
              FontSize="24"/>

           <Label Text="{Binding Department}"
              FontSize="18"
              Opacity="0.6"/>
         </StackLayout>
       </ViewCell>
     </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>


 </ListView>

</ContentPage>
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using XamarinFormsDemo.Models;
using XamarinFormsDemo.Services;

namespace XamarinFormsDemo.ViewModels
    {
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private List<Employee> _employeesList;

    public List<Employee> EmployeesList
    {
        get { return _employeesList; }
        set
        {
            _employeesList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        InitializeDataAsync();
    }

    private async Task InitializeDataAsync()
    {
        var employeesServices = new EmployeesServices();

        EmployeesList = await employeesServices.GetEmployeesAsync();
    }



    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    }
}
```

EmployeesServices.cs

```
using Plugin.RestClient;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using XamarinFormsDemo.Models;

namespace XamarinFormsDemo.Services
{
public class EmployeesServices
{


     public async Task<List<Employee>> GetEmployeesAsync()
     {
        RestClient<Employee> restClient = new RestClient<Employee>();

        var employeesList =  await restClient.GetAsync();

        return employeesList;

     }

    }
}
```

Comment: you need to perform some rudimentary debuggging to determine where the problem is.  Have you attempted that?  You appear to repeatedly post the exact same question without any new information to allow us to help you.  For example, adding a simple Debug.Writeline(employeeList.Count()) in your GetEmployeeAsync() would tell you whether or not your service is returing data to the client.

Comment: can you please teach me how to do that debugging thing you stated Sir?

Comment: Have you allowed in the Android's Manifest file to allow access to the internet?  Example here, https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/general/projects/add_permissions_to_android_manifest/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `GetEmployeesAsync()` function should return a `ObservableCollection<Employee>` and not a `List<Employee>`, I think your view will only be updated when the binding of the ListView is set to a ObservableCollection.

If that's not the problem you could check in the debugger if your EmployeesList is populated with data at all.

**Edit:**
In your MainViewModel, change `private List<Employee> _employeesList;` to `private ObservableCollection<Employee> _employeesList;` and `public List<Employee> EmployeesList` to `public ObservableCollection<Employee> EmployeesList`

In your InitializeDataAsync() method change

```
EmployeesList = await employeesServices.GetEmployeesAsync();
```

to

```
var templist = await employeesServices.GetEmployeesAsync();
foreach (var e in templist)
{
    EmployeesList.Add(e);
}
```

Also I'm not sure if you can set your binding context like this in xamarin, you could try to do this in the CodeBehind of the page.

Comment: @steffdev I've tried that before but I don't know if I've done it correctly. Can you please how am I going to change my codes?